# facebook like button with message

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Can anybody tell how is it possible to create a facebook like button with the option to add a message? example can be found here http://www.familycircle.com/style/beauty/hair/summer-hairstyles/ 
If user does not write anything as a message, the button behaves like normal like button. If user writes a message, it will appear on his/her wall. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Facebook says:

> When will users have the option to add a comment to the like?

If you are using the XFBML version of the Like button, users will always have the option to add a comment. If you are using the iframe version of the button, users will have the option to comment if you are using the standard layout. If users do add a comment, the story published back to Facebook is given more prominence.

[Like Button](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/)

Answer (score 0):

that's the normal behavior of facebook's like button. You have the option of writing a comment or message, and here's how I do it, with HTML5

put this after the body tag

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=YOURAPPID";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
```

put this where you want to see the button

```
 <div class="fb-like" data-href="http://someurl.com" data-send="true" data-width="450" data-show-faces="true"></div>
```

Or create yours [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/)